# Валидация полей в форме регистрации

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, валидация

### Нужно валидировать `input` по шаблону, т.е:

```
 <input name="reg-name-n" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ім'я" pattern="^[А-ЯІЇ][а-яії]{2,9}" title="Від 3 до 10 символів. Перша велика." required>
```

И если, нету никаких проблем с вводом или введено по `pattern`, то добавить этому `input`'у `class="has-success"`, используя `.keyup()`.

---

И если у меня например три разных `pattern'a`, то как упростить код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно на порядок проще, например, использовать селектор :valid.

```
input[type="text"]:valid {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Если все условия выполнены, просто используется стиль под валидный инпут.